# double.TryParse() Returns zero (0) when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, loops, do-while, tryparse

So when I'm dealing with numbers, everything works fine, it's just when I use non-numeric entries. (I put comments where the problems are)

When you enter anything that's not a number, it's supposed to display an error message, then prompt you again to enter a valid entry. If you enter another non-numeric value, instead of staying in the loop, the tryParse changes the value to 0 and therefore exits the loop and finishes the program. How do I get around this?

I only want to exit the loop when I enter 0, not a character that triggers tryParse to changes the character into 0.

I've tried deleting the tryParse at the end, but the first condition in the if statement makes it false and therefore diameter still becomes 0.

```
    static void Main()
    {
    const double MINIMUM_DIAMETER = 12.0;
    const double MAXIMUM_DIAMETER = 36.0;
    double diameter, radius, area, sliceArea;
    string userInput;

    Console.Write("\nPlease enter the diameter of your pizza: ");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        do
        {
            if (double.TryParse(userInput, out diameter) == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nENTRY NON-NUMBERIC ERROR\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Pizza must have a numeric diameter. You entered: \"{0}\"\n", userInput);
                Console.WriteLine("Please try again.\n");

                //**if userInput isn't valid, diameter becomes 0**
            }
            else
            {
                if (diameter < MINIMUM_DIAMETER || diameter > MAXIMUM_DIAMETER)
                {
                    //not important
                }
                else
                {
                    //not important
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\nPlease enter the diameter of your pizza (0 to end program): ");
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            double.TryParse(userInput, out diameter);
            Console.Clear();

            //**if userInput isn't valid, diameter becomes 0 and exits loop**

        } while (diameter != 0);
    }
```

Comment: You're calling TryParse() twice. Check the return value both times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> //**if userInput isn't valid, diameter becomes 0**

If this is the case, *and*

> //**if userInput isn't valid, diameter becomes 0 and exits loop**

Then the problem is you're setting diameter to 0 outside of what you've shared? Making the check for 0 in the else protects it from the defaulted 0 from TryParsing the arg.

[This link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wTjb6v) above is to see the below code in action:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string userInput;
        double diameter;
        Console.Write("\nPlease enter the diameter of your pizza: ");
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        while(true)
        {
            var isDouble = double.TryParse(userInput, out diameter) == true;

            if (!isDouble)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nENTRY NON-NUMBERIC ERROR\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Pizza must have a numeric diameter. You entered: \"{0}\"\n", userInput);
                Console.WriteLine("Please try again.\n");
                diameter = 0;
                //**if userInput isn't valid, diameter becomes 0**
            }
            else
            {
                if (diameter == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n Exit initiated");
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.Write("\nPlease enter the diameter of your pizza (0 to end program): ");
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            double.TryParse(userInput, out diameter);
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```